# How to get custom button designed with background color and rectangle?

Tags: gwt

I am working with GWT. i have a requirement where i need to show the button as below.Please help me how to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GWT [Button](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html) class and style it the way you need. For example, if you're using UiBinder:

```
<g:Button ui:field="button" styleName="my-button">
    <ui:msg key="myButtonMsg">Button</ui:msg>
</g:Button>
```

with your own css class like

```
.my-button {
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you need the text to have white box around it then add `<span>` around button text and add `color: black;` and `background-color: white;` properties for the `span`.

Comment: PushButton also has nice features - you can define up, hover, down, etc. states in your uibinder as (I think) arbitrary HTML